# Exit code from qx// within Perl's Simple HTTP Server is always -1?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use Perl's `HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI` module to run a command on a remote machine and return its output using `qx//`, but `$?` only ever seems to return `-1` - whether the command succeeds or not (and I'm quite keen to know whether it succeeds or not).

In particular, I've changed the line setting `$who` in the example on the `HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI` documentation page [http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Server::Simple#EXAMPLE](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aServer%3a%3aSimple#EXAMPLE) to this command:

```
my $who = qx/cat some_file/."\nReturns $?";
```

but `$?` displays as `-1` whether the file exists or not. It's obviously basically working because the file's contents are shown if it exists. Contrast this with

```
perl -le 'print qx/cat some_file/."\nReturns $?"'
```

which shows it returning `256` on failure or `0` on success. And incidentally in the error case, it reports the failure to `stderr` - not something the Simple case does.

Is there something special I should be doing with `$?`?

I'm on Perl 5.14.2, Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tracked through `HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI` and it seems that it sets `$SIG{'CHLD'}='IGNORE'` as a precaution against zombie processes.

Setting `local $SIG{'CHLD'}='DEFAULT'` immediately before my invocation of `qx//` allows me access to the return code.